# Gradient - Cross Browser uniformity

Tags: css, cross-browser, gradient

I was testing gradient compatibility across all browsers and I found that the gradient had different effects on FireFox. Allow me to demonstrate the test.

**The Code**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top left , white , black 25%);
                background: -o-linear-gradient(top left , white , black 25%);
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left , white , black 25%);
                background: -khtml-linear-gradient(top left , white , black 25%);
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(top left , white , black 25%);
                background:  linear-gradient(top left , white , black 25%);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Results:

Google Chrome - 35.0
[image: Google Chrome - Version 35.0.1916.153 m]

FireFox - 30.0
[image: FireFox - 30.0]

IE11
[image: IE 11]

Opera 22.0
[image: Opera 22.0]

Safari 5.1.7
[image: Safari 5.1.7]

As you can see the gradient takes a different shape in case of Firefox. How to overcome this limitation?

Comment: maybe try using `to bottom right` instead of `top left`

Comment: try to generate http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: I know about many generators , But I would like to code it myself. And thus the test. And CSS3 Now promises cross browser uniformity and the test differed the statement.

Comment: @Genocide_Hoax: Can you try the code which I updated and let me know whether you have any queries.

Comment: couldn't believe what you said was wrong, I've just tried making some demo myself and in fact it runs OK on FF 30 http://jsfiddle.net/rNybk/

Comment: @KingKing yes that's what I was looking for. can you please explain the significance of height in your code. Cause that's the only difference I can find.

Comment: screenshot http://i.imgur.com/uSC0BpZ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the `body` does not have explicit `height` set, by default its margin is about `8px`, so its height is just about `8px`. Here in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/68KXD/), we set `background-repeat` to `no-repeat`, you'll see why by default (`repeat`) it renders to what you saw. However I have to admit that there is a special thing about the `body` element. Looks like the `background` can still render ***outside*** the body. You can use element inspector to see that the body's height is in fact just about `8px`. But the background can still be rendered out of it. We can solve this by setting the height explicitly:

```
body {
    /* ... */
    height:100vh;
}
```

Or:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Or you can also set the `background-size` explicitly:

```
body {
   /* ... */
   background-size:100vw 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this.  http://jsfiddle.net/Vca7f/1/ this will work in IE9 also. to generate more gradient you can visit http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ its very good tool for generating gradient.

```
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
```

Comment: The results are different in FireFox again. And I dont want to generate gradient I would like to code it myself. And thus the test.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will be helpful to you which supports all the browsers:

CSS:

```
div{
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    background:#000;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff 0%, #000 36%, #000 51%, #000 71%, #000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff 0%, #000 36%, #000 51%, #000 71%, #000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff 0%, #000 36%, #000 51%, #000 71%, #000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #fff), color-stop(36%, #000), color-stop(51%, #000), color-stop(71%, #000), color-stop(100%, #000));/* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff 0%, #000 36%, #000 51%, #000 71%, #000 100%); /* IE 10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #fff 0%, #000 36%, #000 51%, #000 71%, #000 100%);/* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fff', endColorstr='#000', GradientType=1 );/* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */

}
```

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

IE9 Support:

Support for full multi-stop gradients with IE9 (using SVG).
Add a "gradient" class to all your elements that have a gradient, 
and add the following override to your HTML to complete the IE9 support:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]
<style type="text/css">
.gradient {
filter: none;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/D26ar/)

Comment: using `-45deg` or `135deg` is totally a different thing. Try resizing your window and see why it is different.

Comment: The motive of this question is not how to achieve that gradient, I can easily use a generator to do it , just like you did. The motive is the reason behind the behavior and how to overcome it using the same snippet provided.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers, while doing a good job at solving the problem, don't address the actual question, which is: why don't all browsers behave the same with this source?

The answer is, Quirks mode. Different browsers have different quirks!
So the way to make the example code come out the same is to insert a proper DOCTYPE declaration on top

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

so that the document is displayed in Standards mode. Then the differences will disappear; all browsers will show it the way Firefox does now.